# Update to linux-image-5.19.0-1020-azure in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS breaks usb devices

Tags: usb, kernel, mouse

Yesterday my system updated to linux-image-5.19.0-1020-azure. The immediate discernible consequence was that my mouse / pointer froze. Further investigation showed that /proc/bus/input/devices lists no usb devices. For the time being my work-around is to boot into linux-image-5.15.0-60-generic, which works just fine.

Is there a permanent fix for this? As an aside, what's the point of linux-image-5.19.0-1020-azure, and does it have anything to do with Microsoft's cloud platform?

Here's what's currently installed:

apt list --installed | grep azure

```
linux-image-5.19.0-1020-azure/jammy-proposed,now 5.19.0-1020.21~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-5.19.0-1020-azure/jammy-proposed,now 5.19.0-1020.21~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1020-azure/jammy-proposed,now 5.19.0-1020.21~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-nvidia-525-azure-edge/jammy-proposed,now 5.19.0-1020.21~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1020-azure/jammy-proposed,now 5.19.0-1020.21~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-1020-azure/jammy-proposed,now 5.19.0-1020.21~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

======================================================

Follow up:

After purging azure and linux-image-5.15.0-66-generic linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-66-generic per Pilot6 (thank you!) everything is back to normal. However, I'm still getting an "Update Notifier" prompt to install azure. Why?

Follow up follow up:

My best guess as to what happened is that I (for some reason I can't remember) had a Microsoft repository in my sources. I got an "Update Notifier" prompt to install the azure kernel, which I naively accepted. I removed the MS source and now no longer get the "Update Notifier".

Comment: System couldn't upgrade to this kernel by itself. What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ok, I'm speaking loosely here. Not sure of the correct terminology, but I was prompted to upgrade and said yes. Start-Date: 2023-02-09  19:35:35
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-upgrade-system' sender=':1.74'
Install: linux-headers-5.15.0-66-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-66.73, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-66-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-66.73, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-1020-azure:amd64 (5.19.0-1020.21~22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-5.19.0-1020-azure:amd64 (5.19.0-1020.21~22.04.1, automatic),etc.

Comment: Please don't post information to comments. [edit] your question.

Comment: Remove this kernel.

Comment: Why did you enable `proposed` repository? It as a bad idea. Don't tell me that you didn't do that either.

Comment: I updated the answer, remove meta packages too. Purging 5.15 was wrong

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally installed a wrong kernel.

Reboot with the `linux-image-5.15.0-60-generic` kernel

Then run

```
sudo apt purge linux-azure linux-image-azure
sudo apt purge linux-image-5.19.0-1020-azure linux-modules-5.19.0-1020-azure linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1020-azure linux-modules-nvidia-525-azure-edge linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1020-azure inux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-1020-azure
```

and reboot.

Also disable proposed repository in Software & Updates. it can break your system.

Comment: Why was I "accidentally" prompted to install the wrong kernel? It's not my practice to willy nilly install kernels.

Comment: You or someone else ran a wrong command in a terminal before. If it is a laptop, desktop or a server running on a real hardware, there shouldn't be that kernel at all. Someone had added it.

Comment: Following your suggestion, which looks good, I get this: The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-1020-azure  How do I avoid that?

Comment: Please add TO YOUR QUESTION output of `apt list --installed | grep azure`

Comment: It seems that it is not full output. There should be something like `linux-azure` and `linux-image-azure`.